# Web parsing with python beautifulsoup producing inconsistent result

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to parse the table of [this site](http://www.athamap.de/search_gene.php?agi=At1g76540%0D%0AAt3g12280%0D%0AAt4g28980%0D%0AAt4g37630%0D%0AAt5g11300%0D%0AAt5g27620%0D%0A&upstream=-500&downstream=50&restriction=0&sortBy1=gen&sortBy2=fac&sortBy3=pos&familySelected%5BARF%5D=on&familySelected%5BCAMTA%5D=on&familySelected%5BGARP%2FARR-B%5D=on&formSubmitted=TRUE). I am using python beautiful soup to do that. While it's producing correct output in my Ubuntu 14.04 machine, it's producing wrong output in my friend's windows machine. I am pasting the code snippet here:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def buildURL(agi, families):
    #agi and families contains space seperated string of genes and families
    genes = agi.split(" ")
    families = families.split(" ")
    base_url = "http://www.athamap.de/search_gene.php"

    url = base_url

    if len(genes):
        url = url + "?agi="
        for i, gene in enumerate(genes):
            if i>0:
                url = url + "%0D%0A"
            url = url + gene

    url = url + "&upstream=-500&downstream=50&restriction=0&sortBy1=gen&sortBy2=fac&sortBy3=pos"

    for family in families:
        family = family.replace("/", "%2F")
        url = url +"&familySelected%5B"+family+"%5D=on"
    url = url + "&formSubmitted=TRUE"
    return url

def fetch_html(agi, families):

    url = buildURL(agi, families)
    response = requests.get(url)
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(str(response.text), "lxml")

    divs = soup.find_all('div')

    seldiv = ""
    for div in divs:
        try:
            if div["id"] == "geneAnalysisDetail":
                '''
                    This div contains interesting data
                '''
                seldiv = div
        except:
            None

    return seldiv

def parse(seldiv):
    soup = seldiv
    rows= soup.find_all('tr')

    attributes =["Gene", "Factor", "Family", "Position", "Relative orientation", "Relative Distance", "Max score", "Threshold Score", "Score"]

    print attributes
    save_rows = []
    for i in range(2, len(rows)):
        cols = rows[i].find_all('td')
        lst = []
        for j,col in enumerate(cols):
            if j==0:
                lst.append(re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '',str(col.contents[1].contents[0])))
            elif j==1:
                lst.append(str(col.contents[1].contents[0]))
            elif j==2:
                lst.append(str(col.contents[0]))
            elif j==3:
                lst.append(str(col.contents[1].contents[0]))
            else:
                lst.append(str(col.contents[0]))
        save_rows.append(lst)
    return save_rows
```

Any idea what could go wrong here? I have tried with and without lxml.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean "it's producing the wrong output"? Do you get an error, do you get different values?

Comment: different values.

Comment: Can't access the URL.

Comment: What different values its producing ? Is it giving values with `tags` in some cases on windows ??

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the table this way and should work well on both machine. `buildURL` function should be left unchanged.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def fetch_html(url):

    response = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

    seldiv = soup.find("div", id="geneAnalysisDetail")

    return seldiv

def parse(url):
    soup = fetch_html(url)
    rows= soup.find_all("tr")

    attributes = ["Gene", "Factor", "Family", "Position", "Relative orientation", "Relative Distance", "Max score", "Threshold Score", "Score"]

    save_rows = []
    for i in range(2, len(rows)):
        cols = rows[i].find_all("td")
        lst = []
        for col in cols:
            text = col.get_text()
            text = text.strip(" ")
            text = text.strip("\n")
            lst.append(text)
        save_rows.append(lst)
    return save_rows

url = "http://www.athamap.de/search_gene.php?agi=At1g76540%0D%0AAt3g12280%0D%0AAt4g28980%0D%0AAt4g37630%0D%0AAt5g11300%0D%0AAt5g27620%0D%0A&upstream=-500&downstream=50&restriction=0&sortBy1=gen&sortBy2=fac&sortBy3=pos&familySelected[ARF]=on&familySelected[CAMTA]=on&familySelected[GARP%2FARR-B]=on&formSubmitted=TRUE"
save_rows = parse(url)
for row in save_rows:
    print(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you didn't add user agent for the requests. Different user agent will get different result sometime, especially from weird website. Here is a list of all possible agents, just choose one. It doesn't have to be your machine

```
    USER_AGENTS = [
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.79 Safari/537.36 Edge/14.14393',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.110 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0',
'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0'
]
```

Comment: You can also pip install fake_useragent and use UserAgent().random